# How to input from multiple couchdb dbs

Tags: logstash, couchdb, elastic-stack

How can I input all databases which have names that start with "xxxx" into the Logstash?

Something like this:

```
input {
    db => xxxx*
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use multiple inputs, one for each couchdb that you want to read.

```
input {
   couchdb_changes {
      db => xxxxA
      ....
   }
   couchdb_changes {
      db => xxxxB
      ....
   }
}
```